# this keyword gives null reference error in browser after compiled from typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, gulp

I ran a gulp task to convert my angualr typescript code(boot.ts and UtilComponent.ts) to js code. When my boot.ts file is compiled with gulp task it generates utilscript.js file and its .map file. But when i try to use utilscript.js file in chrome browser with an index.html and a script tag it gives an error " Cannot read 'sayHelloWorld' of null". All my event handler methods like onclick or onchange methods work fine though.

My boot.ts file:

```
import { UtilComponent} from './util-component';

const utilComponent= new UtilComponent();
```

My UtilComponent.ts content:

```
export class UtilComponent {

    msg: string = 'Hello World';

    constructor() {
        this.initializeMessage()
    }

    initializeMessage() {   
        this.sayHelloWorld();
    }

    sayHelloWorld(){
        console.log("sayHelloWorld Method not implemented."+this.name);
    }
}
```

`this.sayHelloWorld()` line gives  Cannot read 'sayHelloWorld' of null.

My `gulpfile.js`:

```
         var gulp = require('gulp');
        var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        var browserify = require("browserify");
        var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
        var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
        var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
        var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
        var tsify = require("tsify");

        gulp.task('ng-build', function(cb) {
            console.log('running ng build...');
            exec('ng build', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log(stdout);
                console.log(stderr);
                cb(err);
                return true;
            });
        });
        gulp.task('utilscript', function() {
            return browserify({
                    basedir: '.',
                    debug: true,
                    entries: 'scripts/boot.ts'
                })
                .plugin(tsify)
                .bundle()
                .pipe(source('utilscript.js'))
                .pipe(buffer())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
        });

        gulp.task('default', [ 'utilscript']);
```

My `package.json`:

```
    {
      "name": "util-chromejs",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.6.8",
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/chrome": "0.0.54",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "browserify": "^14.5.0",
        "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
        "del": "3.0.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.3",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^5.3.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tsify": "^3.0.3",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2",
        "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
      }
    }
```

Update :If i move sayHelloWorld function out of class and make it below then it works.

```
 export function sayHelloWorld{

 }
```

Comment: Please post the code where you create an `UtilComponent` object instance. I suspect your `this` variable is not its intended value (are you in an event-handler, for example?). This often happens when calling TypeScript code directly from JavaScript without calling `bind` to set `this` correctly.

Comment: @Dai You are right. It was inside an event handler. Sorry my code didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use arrow function to set `this` context correctly. Also see [this in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript)

```
export class UtilComponent {
    msg: string = 'Hello World';

    constructor() {
         this.initializeMessage()
    }

    initializeMessage = () => {   
         this.sayHelloWorld(); // without arrow function, the context will be initializeMessage function and thus throwing the error.
    }

    sayHelloWorld = () => {
       console.log("sayHelloWorld Method not implemented."+this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like `initializeMessage = () => { ` because it means that `initializeMessage` stops being a method and becomes a function-property (with implied mutability). While the two behave the same in practice it just doesn't sit-right with me.

Comment: Another way of doing it would be binding the function to `this` context in the constructor.  `constructor() { this.initializeMessage = this.initializeMessage.bind(this); this.initializeMessage(); }`.